# ¿Cómo restringir la entrada de caracteres, para aceptar únicamente números decimales?

Tags: python, tkinter

Quiero restringir la entrada de caracteres en python aceptando solo numeros decimales, quiero que solo se ponga un punto y claro después de un numero y antes de un numero. Por el momento mi código borra todos los puntos puestos y toma como Decimal a cualquier numero que tenga uno o varios puntos

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter as tk

Raiz=Tk()

def Funcion():
    if valor.get().replace('.','').isdigit() and len(valor.get())<=7:
        messagebox.showinfo('Mensaje','Es un numero decimal')
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo('Mensaje','No un numero decimal')

valor=StringVar()

ttk.Entry(Raiz,textvariable=valor).place(x=1,y=1)
ttk.Button(Raiz,text="Confirmar",command=Funcion).place(x=5,y=30)

Raiz.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que entiendo, quieres forzar a que lo que se introduzca sea la representación de un número de punto flotante. Por tanto puedes intentar convertir en `float` ese valor y si ocurre una excepción, eso indicaría que no es una representación válida para un flotante.

Por ejemplo:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter as tk

Raiz=Tk()

def Funcion():
    v = valor.get()
    try:
        float(v)
        messagebox.showinfo('Mensaje','Es un numero decimal')
    except:
        messagebox.showinfo('Mensaje','No un numero decimal')

valor=StringVar()

ttk.Entry(Raiz,textvariable=valor).place(x=1,y=1)
ttk.Button(Raiz,text="Confirmar",command=Funcion).place(x=5,y=30)

Raiz.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Una forma es validar el input del usuario y solo permitir el ingreso si el resultado es lo que esperamos. Esta sería una prueba de concepto:

```
import tkinter as tk

class window:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.panel = tk.Frame(master)
        self.panel.grid()
        self.button = tk.Button(self.panel, text = "Salir", command = self.panel.quit)
        self.button.grid()

        """        
        '%d'    Action code: 0 for an attempted deletion, 1 for an attempted insertion, or -1 if the callback was called for focus in, focus out, or a change to the textvariable.
        '%i'    When the user attempts to insert or delete text, this argument will be the index of the beginning of the insertion or deletion. If the callback was due to focus in, focus out, or a change to the textvariable, the argument will be -1.
        '%P'    The value that the text will have if the change is allowed.
        '%s'    The text in the entry before the change.
        '%S'    If the call was due to an insertion or deletion, this argument will be the text being inserted or deleted.
        '%v'    The current value of the widget's validate option.
        '%V'    The reason for this callback: one of 'focusin', 'focusout', 'key', or 'forced' if the textvariable was changed.
        '%W'    The name of the widget.
        """        
        vcmd = (master.register(self.validate),
                '%d', '%i', '%P', '%s', '%S', '%v', '%V', '%W')

        self.text = tk.Entry(self.panel, validate = 'key', validatecommand = vcmd)
        self.text.grid()
        self.text.focus()

    def validate(self, action, index, value_if_allowed,
                       prior_value, text, validation_type, trigger_type, widget_name):


        if len(value_if_allowed)==0:
            return True

        if text in '0123456789.-+':
            try:
                float(value_if_allowed)
                return True
            except ValueError:
                return False
        else:
            return False

root = tk.Tk()
window(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Hemos creado una función de validación `validate` que se evalúa con cada tecla ingresada, lo que hace es solo permitir el ingreso si:

- El resultado final será una cadena en blanco
- Es uno de los caracteres válidos
- El resultado final es convertible a un float

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959815/restricting-the-value-in-tkinter-entry-widget